# How to handle Hiddenfield values codebehind and return them to CS Page even after Session Time out period

Tags: asp.net, session-timeout, hiddenfield

I have an aspx page where some values are handled using hidden fields throughout and finally the whole result set is returned to the aspx.cs page.if this result set is returned within the session time out period then the save is successfull else if it is after the session time out period then the hiddenvalues are not taken fully and save doesnt work.How can i make save successfull inspite of adding datas after session time out period

Answer (score 0):

Processing of POST data (where hidden input will be coming) and session state handling are unrelated things as far as ASP.NET pipeline goes. So its likely that your own code that is depending upon session state is causing the issue.

In case, you are unable to locate the trouble-some issue, I will advise you to post a small code sample where problem is reproducible (More often than not, you may find the issue while cutting down the code to meaningful sample).